# Merging branches which have already been merged before

Tags: git, github

My structure is as follows:

```
Branch 1 - A -- B -- C -- D --- E -- G -- H
Branch 2 -            \ -- F - / -- I
```

Now I want to merge branch 2 into branch 1 again but git says *`Already upto date`*.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried a `git fetch`, your local branch 1 might still be on E.

Comment: Yeah but it is of no help.

Comment: **Got it**. I also had to switch to branch 2 and pull again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Helpful command to know is `git fetch --all` and `git pull --all` which updates all branches, this way you don't have to switch branches.

Answer (score 0):

Since branch `1` already contain the changes of branch 2 you will need to checkout the branch with the latest code - the commits which are not merged yet.

Once you checkout the branch you will be able to merge it back to the original branch.

---

When git asked to merge 2 branches he then check for [`merge-base` (click to read more)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base)

In your case it will find that the branch is already up to date, This is why yo will have to check out branch #2 and then pull branch #1 into it.

> git merge-base finds best common ancestor(s) between two commits to use in a three-way merge.
>
> One common ancestor is better than another common ancestor if the latter is an ancestor of the former.
>
> A common ancestor that does not have any better common ancestor is a best common ancestor, i.e. a merge base. Note that there can be more than one merge base for a pair of commits